# How is it organized Cramer's rule when determinant is zero

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

\begin{cases}
 x +   2y - z = 0 
\\  
   2x +3y – 2z = -1
\\
  -x + y + z = 3
\end{cases}

$$
\left |
\begin{matrix}
1&2&-1 \\
2&3&-2 \\
-1&1&1
\end{matrix}
\right|=0.
$$

How should I organize equations to solve with Cramer's Rule

Comment: Cramer’s rule is invalid in such a case. You’ll have to use some other method.

Comment: If the determinant is zero you **can't** use Cramer's rule. In fact there cannot be a unique solution.

Comment: Your determinant's very first entry is wrong: it should be $\;-1\;$ ...

Comment: Yes, I corrected.

Comment: With the last edition of your question your system ins incongruent = it has no solution,. as you can easily check by reducing by rows the system's matrix.

Answer (score 3):

Since the determinant is $0$, the system either has no solution or it has infinitely many.

Since $\det\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\2&3\end{bmatrix}\ne0$, you can consider
$$
\begin{cases}
-x+2y=z\\
2x+3y=2z-1
\end{cases}
$$
Solve it with Cramer's rule and substitute in the last equation to verify whether it holds or not.

Comment: Thank you. This is the solution I want.